# Taking the input field from a JSON

Tags: html, jquery, json, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test AJAX</title>
    </head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function send()
    {
    var index = $('#index').val();
     $(document).ready(function() {
           
            $("#submit").click(function(event){
               $.getJSON('bursa.json', function(jd) {
                  $('#Reserved').html('<p>' + jd.response[0].index + '</p>');
               });
            });
               
         });
    }
    </script>
    
    <body>
    <form method="get">
    Select <input type="text" id="index"><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="send()" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="Reserved" style="border:1px solid red; height: 300px; width:400px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm a beginner with Jquery and I've been trying to get some data from some JSON file I created for a test. Basically what I want is to be able to allow the user to select the field he wants from the json document. My json file looks like this

```
"response": [
        {
            "c": "205.84",
            "h": "206.70",
            "l": "204.27",
            "ch": "-1.57",
            "cp": "-0.76%",
            "t": "1611349199",
            "s": "BA",
            "cty": "united-states",
            "ccy": "USD",
            "exch": "NYSE",
            "id": "1",
            "tm": "2021-01-22 20:59:59"
        },
```

If I try to print jd.response[0].cty for example it correctly shows "united-states", but what I want as I said is to allow the user to select his own field.. With what I've done so far it only shows "undefined". Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You don't need `document.ready` inside of a function

Comment: Rather than `.index`, use `[index]`

Comment: Hey I posted an answer for it, it would be great if you accepted and upvoted!

Comment: 6minutes cd, sorry I'm still new here, soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.index`, use `[index]`:

```
$('#Reserved').html('<p>' + jd.response[0][index] + '</p>');
```

Also called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)